# BAD ACCESS when using nested blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Here's the problem: I need to create an alert from a non-UI thread. But when I do it with blocks, I get a "BAD ACCESS" error.
Here's the code:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{       
        [currentUser updateWithFacebookUser:user errorBlock:^(void) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Facebook login was unsuccessfult. It's already in the system." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            [alert show];
        }];
}
```

In updateWithFacebookUser:errorBlock:

```
- (void)updateWithFacebookUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)facebookUser errorBlock:(void (^)(void))errorBlock
{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        errorBlock();
    }];    
}
```

What surprised me is that when I show the alert without any blocks, everything is okay:

```
  - (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
    {       
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:@"Facebook login was unsuccessfult. It's already in the system." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                [alert show];
            }];
    }
```

Also I noticed that the alert is shown, and only then the error occurs. What can be the problem?

Comment: Last answer was accepted by accident, the solution didn't really work...

Comment: Agreed. The problem undoubtedly rests elsewhere, not in this code, which looks fine. Perhaps your `UIAlertViewDelegate` object? (Try using `nil` for the `delegate` and see if the problem goes away.) It's hard to say on the basis of what has been shared thus far. Try setting breakpoints in all of these relevant methods and identify precisely which one is causing the "BAD ACCESS" error. (Sometimes using [exception breakpoints](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) can be helpful in diagnosing these issues.)

Comment: When you have a crash, **post the backtrace**.    As @Rob said, the problem likely happens elsewhere, but it is impossible to say, because you didn't post any details about the crash itself.

Comment: A little too quick on the draw there. My apologies for the inaccurate answer and clutter. I've removed my answer.

Comment: I changed delegate to nil and it worked, thanks!